# Can't get xmlelements' values when it uppercase

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jaxb

Can't get the xml elements "CustNo" and "Name" value in the POST API using Spring Boot (It happens with the elements' names in uppercase)

The Custromer class:

```java
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "custNo",
            "name"
    })
    @XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
    public class Customer {
            
        @XmlElement(name = "CustNo")
        private int custNo;
        
        @XmlElement(name = "Name")
        private String name;
    
        @XmlElement(name = "CustNo")
        public int getCustNo() {
            return custNo;
        }
    
        public void setCustNo(int custNo) {
            this.custNo = custNo;
        }
    
        @XmlElement(name = "Name")
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
```

the XML request Body:

```xml
    <customer>
        <CustNo>100</CustNo>
        <Name>Alex</Name>
    </customer>
```

Controller:

```java
    @PostMapping(path = "/save-cust-info", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public String customerInformation(@RequestBody Customer cust) {
        return "Customer information saved successfully ::." + cust.getCustNo() + " " + cust.getName();
    }
```

POM dependencies:

```xml
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The result is: `"Customer information saved successfully ::.0 null United States"`

But value CustNo is 0 and Name is null. What did i wrong?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: It looks like spring doesn't respect JAXB annotations here.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Cezary Butler, spring ignored annotations
the solution - is to replace @XmlElement to @JacksonXmlProperty
This is how i solved it:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "customer")




public class Customer {

    private String country;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="CustNo")
    private int custNo;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Name")
    private String name;

    public Customer() {

    }


    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public int getCustNo() {
        return custNo;
    }

    public void setCustNo(int custNo) {
        this.custNo = custNo;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and pom.xml:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
```